# Using NearbySearch in Google Maps API Places Library not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

in Google Maps API Places Library, I'm using the following code. However, when user clicks the button with id="find", whilst the map centers itself to the user's location, no nearby places are returned. I'm mixing code from the places library and the geolocation API, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<script>

  var map, infoWindow;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 51.516401, lng: -0.152218},
      zoom: 17
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    $("#find").click(function(){

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(pos);

        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat,pos.lng);  

        var request = {
            location: pyrmont,
            radius: '1000',
            query: 'restaurant'
        };

        service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map)

        service.textSearch(request, callback);


      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {

      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  });

}

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }

    function callback(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var place = results[i];
        createMarker(results[i]);
            }
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: createMarker is not defined`

Comment: You didn't define createMarker function

Answer (score 0):

add createMarker function

```
function createMarker(place) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
    })
}
```